# Can't create Custom Action in Display Form Ribbon when using InfoPath form?

Tags: infopath, custom-actions, display-form

I have a SharePoint list which uses InfoPath forms. I've created a Custom Action on SharePoint Designer for that list, located on the Display Form Ribbon, but when I go to view an item there is no change.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it to do with that I'm using InfoPath forms?

Comment: have you solve this issue?